# Chromecast - return to homepage when done casting

Tags: ios, chromecast

I'm writing an iOS app that casts pictures. I want to make it in a way that when the user quits the picture viewing scene, it goes back to the homepage (the one displaying app's name) on the big screen. I've tried calling the `stop` method for `mediaControlChannel` and it's not going back to the homepage. So apparently this is not the one I'm looking for. So which method should I call to make it go back to homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK doesn't have any understanding of your "homepage"; that is a concept in your app so you need to write your receiver so that if user ends the process of viewing picture, it switches to that page. Whether receiver on its own can determine that the above process has ended or sender has to signal the receiver depends on your application and its details but regardless, going to your home page is an action that you have to define and handle.